# Changing Label/Button Text colour dynamically based on the dynamically changing background

Tags: swift, user-experience, textcolor

I know it may sound a little bit of a drag to ask this question but I am curious if anything like this is available.

I am building a app in which the background image (covers full view with a blur effect) of each view controller changes dynamically. This background image will be in all the view controllers, each one having a different set of UIControls (Labels, Buttons, Table Views, Collection Views, containers, tabs, etc).

Sometimes when the background image is very light, the foreground texts (labels, buttons) with white text colour are not visible at all. Also the vice versa is a problem too.

So I would like to know if there is any way to change the foreground text colour dynamically based on its background.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I faced the same problem, And I think what you looking for is either image is bright or dark so that you can set property accordingly Hope this will help.

Create observer, everytime image change it will check if its a dark image or bright and based on that will call the function UIForDarkImage and UIForBrightImage

//ImageView observer to observe the image change and perform the UI action based on the image colour

```
//Your imageView you are using to set image
var imageView: UIImageView {
    didSet {
       if imageView.isDark(image.bounds) { //dont pass the full image bounds pass the rect where your buttons or label places it will save your hell lot of time
          setUIForDarkImage() // here you set buttons and labels color to white or whatever changes you want to perform based dark image
       } 
       else {
         setUIForBrightImage() // here you set buttons and labels color to black or whatever changes you want to perform based bright image
       }
    }
}
```

UIImageViewExtension for checking if Image is a dark image or bright Image.

What happening is, It will go through image pixel-by-pixel and check if the pixel is bright or dark and if we get dark pixels more than the threshold we have set, we will assuming that its a dark image else it's a bright image.

PS: For better efficiency not checking the whole image (for a high-resolution image it will slow down if we will check all pixels) so only checking the part of the image in which we need our button or label, you can set rect based on your requirement. And also scaling by 0.45 to check few pixels in that rect(you can increase or decrease for more/less accuracy).

```
extension UIImageView {
    func isDark(_ rect:CGRect)->Bool {
       let s=image?.cgImage?.cropping(to: rect);
       let data=s?.dataProvider?.data;
       if data == nil {return false;}
       guard let ptr = CFDataGetBytePtr(data) else {return false;}
       let threshold = Int(Double(rect.width * rect.height) * 0.45);
       var dark = 0,len=CFDataGetLength(data);
       for i in stride(from: 0, to: len, by: 4) {
           let r = ptr[i], g = ptr[i+1], b = ptr[i+2];
           if (0.299 * Double(r) + 0.587 * Double(g) + 0.114 * Double(b)) < 100 {dark += 1;}
          if dark > threshold {return true;}
       }
    return false;
  }
}
```

PS: If you also like to know what I am doing in setUIForBrightImage() and setUIForDarkImage do let me know

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do: Create a struct that contains the name of the image view and a tint color to use for your labels, buttons, etc.

Add a property to your view controllers using this new struct. Let's call it `backgroundImageSettings`.

Add a `didSet` method to the property that calls another method `useBackgroundImageSettings()` that installs the image into the background of the view controller's content view, sets the tint color for the view controller's content view, and calls `setNeedsDisplay()` on the content view.. Also call `useBackgroundImageSettings()` in your viewDidLoad so that setting your `backgroundImageSettings` still works even if you view controller's view hasn't been loaded yet.

Answer (score 0):

I like Duncan's answer! An additional step you can take is to set a slight overlay onto your background image.

For example, if you have a background image with really dark colors and you can't see your black text very well, then you can add a layer with a background color of white and an opacity less than 1. That way there's a bit of white to make your text more readable, and you can still see the background image.

```
let overlay = UIView(frame: yourSuperView.bounds)
overlay.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
overlay.layer.opacity = 0.5
yourSuperView.addSubview(overlay)
```